# NewDialog with ProgressBar to execute CustomAction on loading

Tags: dialog, wix, custom-action

Dialog1: contains two radio boxes. 
- When user selects radiobox1 he moves on to the WixUI_Minimal workflow
- When user selects radiobox2 he moves to the Custom UI which starts with Dialog2

Dialog2: contains one progress bar
- I want a custom action CA1 to be called when this dialog opens

I tried the following in Dialog1:
- Publish NewDialog to open Dialog2 with Order 1
- Publish DoAction for CA1 with Order 2
CA1 is not called in this case.

I tried the following in Dialog2
- Placed a Custom Action outside Dialog with Control and Dialog reference.
CA1 is not called in this case.

Is there a way to execute CA1 on opening Dialog2?

Answer (score 0):

*"I tried the following in Dialog1: 
- Publish NewDialog to open Dialog2 with Order 1 
- Publish DoAction for CA1 with Order 2 CA1 is not called in this case."*

I had tried the above but in Dialog2 I had used InstallExecuteSequence instead of InstallUISequence.

By using the InstallUISequence as follows I was able to get the results I needed:

```
<InstallUISequence>
<Custom Action="CA1" Before="ExecuteAction"/>
</InstallUISequence>
```